# How to read HttpWebResponse twice

Tags: c#, .net, streamreader, webrequest, httpwebresponse

How to read HttpWebResponse twise? Is it possible at all?

My code doesnt work and `respStream.Position = 0;` does not help.

Any clue, pls?

```
var data = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);  
var response = (HttpWebResponse)data.GetResponse();

var respStream = response.GetResponseStream();

string responseText;         
using (var reader = new StreamReader(respStream, encoding))
{
     responseText = reader.ReadToEnd().Trim();
}
// Do something and read it again
using (var reader = new StreamReader(respStream, encoding))
{
     responseText = reader.ReadToEnd().Trim();
}
```

Comment: why would you ever want to read it twice? you read it once, and reference the result twice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type that is returned from `response.GetResponseStream()` is `System.Net.ConnectStream`. If you check the property `CanSeek` of this stream you will see that it cannot be seeked, so this means you cannot reset it and read it again:

```
var typeOfStream = respStream.GetType();    // System.Net.ConnectStream
var canSeek = respStream.CanSeek;           // false
```

However, when you read the data to a string you already have the data, so you can use it twice:

```
string responseText1, responseText2;
using (var reader = new StreamReader(respStream, encoding))
{
     responseText1 = reader.ReadToEnd().Trim();
     responseText2 = responseText1;    // you get a copy of response
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem but my stream did't contain string-content but binary data. Since we only can read the ConnectStream once, my solution was to copy it to a MemoryStream:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.foo.bar/binary.file");
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
    var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        responseStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);

        // This one is important so we can read the stream from the beginning.
        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); 

        // Perform my first thing.
        var isValid = Utility.ValidateContent(memoryStream);

        if (isValid)
        {
            // Reset the position to the beginning of the stream again
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); 
            using (var fileStream = File.Create("c:\\temp\\myfile.ext"))
            {
                memoryStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To be clear, if one just needs the string data twice the solution that "dotnetom" provided would be both cleaner and faster.